# Why does only the hot water have low Water Pressure from my 2 handle kitchen faucet?

Tags: faucet, water-pressure

My kitchen faucet is a two handle style with a single delivery spout.  The water pressure for the cold water and for ALL the other water sources in the home work fine.  The water pressure for the hot water in the kitchen has steadily been getting slower and slower. Today it is a VERY small stream.

Answer (score 3):

Your kitchen hot water faucet probably requires replacement (or possibly repair). From your description it sounds like the hot water side has clogged up to the point that it is restricting the water flow. Most likely cause is heavy calcium deposit inside the faucet and/or the hot water piping leading to the kitchen sink.

Comment: Sometimes CaCO3 stones can break loose from the piping, and block entrance to the mix chamber/cartridge under the central faucet. Taking off the faucet piece, and any mixer cartridge, then running the hot (put a pot over it so water doesn't hit the ceiling) will sometimes fix that problem.

Comment: We had a water filter attached to the sink that was causing odd water flow restrictions at random times. I soaked the attachment in vinegar and baking soda overnight and the problem went away. Our water is pretty hard so I’m guessing it was a calcium buildup.

Answer (score 2):

In the order of things I would check:

1. Faucet hose.  Some have filter rings that can get clogged.
2. Shut-off valve if you have one.  Maybe it is turned.  Sometimes there is build-up in these too.  Put a bucket under it and turn it on.  If it comes on full steam then you have a problem up stream.  If it trickles out then you have an issue with shut-off or in your pipes for this branch.
3. Replace faucet.  This is not usually what it is...  Try cleaning faucet with vinegar before doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I once had a shower which had terrible hot water pressure (must have been for decades), and when I finally got ticked off enough to rip things apart (not decades), I eventually worked my way back to a sweated copper 90 degree elbow 3 feet below the tub which was almost completely blocked by excess (absurdly excess) solder. Process somewhat straightforward, if tedious and messy - take things off and see if the water pressure is still terrible, if so, work back further.

So, step one for you is whether there is decent hot pressure at the connection below the sink to the faucet or not. If so, look up to the faucet - if not, look back toward the hot water heater, and keep going until the pressure improves.

Comment: Great process for “debugging” any source of water - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with all the faucets in the house.
After cut out the hot water pipe in pieces to check for inside blockage, they were looking very clean from inside.
Looked inside the heat trap nipple on the hot water outlet, I found the ball was stuck and created a blockage. 
The hot water pressure went back normal after replacing the heat trap nipple.